# How to resize a pdf from 1MB to 400KB

Tags: pdf, resize

I have a pdf file that is 1.1MB of size but I need upload 400kb of that file. Please tell me how to resize the file to get an output of 400kb.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always use a website such as [CompressPDF](http://compress.smallpdf.com) or [Neevia Document Converter](http://convert.neevia.com/pdfcompress) for all of it, it is easy to use, takes a few seconds and knowing anything about PDF is completely optional.